# Quotient with third order polynomial infinity as denominator confusion.

Tags: calculus, limits, exponentiation

The question concerned is:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}[(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{e})^n]^n$

I am reading about limits and have used l'hopitals rule to silmplify the original question to this:

$-\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{2n^3+4n^2+2n}$

the solution says that this simplifies to $-\frac{1}{2}$

I don't understand how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're taking limits over $x\to\infty$ but $x$ doesn't show up in either of your expressions. What do you really mean here?

Comment: @KReiser I meant n instead of x. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Multiply through by $$\dfrac{\frac 1{n^3}}{\frac 1{n^3}}$$